# Can I name my token or smart contract after another token?

Tags: contract-design, tokens

Can I name my token, for example, FakeGolem and put its symbol as FGNT? Is it "legal" if I make profit with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is technically possible yes, but how you intend on using (sharing/selling) the token could have legal implications which are dependant on where you're based.